# Search my site with bing through form without javascript

Tags: javascript, search, query-string, bing

I'm hoping to find a way to use the Bing search engine to search only my site through a html form without javascript. Google handles it this way: http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Sharepoint&as_sitesearch=plop.nl where I can use these fields: as_q and as_sitesearch. Does anybody know of something like this for Bing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the querystring Bing uses for a normal search.

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=my+query&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=
```

Of these, looks like you can drop the sk= and filt=all but that's untested

Comment: Yes, but that is not the question. At the moment i can only find a way to search in just one domain by adding site:www.myurl.com in de q= query argument. I would like to search in my site through the a seperate query string argument like &site=www.myurl.com so that it works without javascript as well